# javascript download audio/mpeg content from different server with different origin

Tags: javascript, file, html, download

Is it possible to download audio/mpeg content from different server with different origin(like my server is www.a.com and the file is in www.b.com) with javascript on the browser.
ps: like download and get 3rd byte of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS doesn't really have any file-based operators, and you'd be running up against the same-origin security policies. You might be able to get the browser to download it by inserting an `<object>` or similar tag into the DOM and have its source be the other server. But then you'd be stuck with a DOM object that wouldn't give you access to the raw bytes of the audio.

Comment: by  saying  file meant may be arraybuffer or something that I can play

Comment: because an arraybuffer can be played in html5 javascript as converting it to Blob object url.